# How to use template literals in a constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm building a To Do list app and have a question regarding OOP and JavaScript. I want to create a value in the Constructor that holds my `taskBody` which contains the HTML and template literal that will be assigned by *either the input value or an eventual population from local storage*. My goal is to re-use this HTML in two separate functions, but I'm stuck with the template literal.

```
class Task {
  constructor() {
    let taskValue //Initializing a variable

    this.taskBody = `<div class="task">
    <span>${taskValue}</span> //Template Literal
      <span class="actions">
       
        <a class="edit-button" title="Edit Task">Edit</a>
        <button class="complete-button" title="Complete Task"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
        
      </span>
    </div>`;

  }

  addTask = () => {
    //Prevent empty task
    if (this.input.value == "") {
      this.setPlaceholder("Please Enter A Task");
      return;
    }

    this.taskValue = this.input.value; //Trying to reassign taskValue to the input value

    this.results.innerHTML += this.taskBody; //Trying to grab the HTML from the constructor and populate with taskValue able

    ls.setLS(this.taskValue); //setting the Local Storage the Task Value, which works
  };

}
```

I expect if I type "Stack Overflow" in the to-do list, "Stack Overflow" populates in the HTML and the Local Storage, however, it only populates in the Local Storage. The todo item is either undefined, null, or empty.

I've tried using `this.taskValue`, `let taskValue = ""`, and `let taskValue = null`, but I get the results described above. Where am I going wrong, and more specifically, how can I reuse the HTML in different functions?

Here's a CodePen where you can see the issue:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/YzWeMaz)

Comment: `class Task() {` is not valid JS. `class Task {` without `()` is.

Comment: Whoops, just a typo there. Thanks, edited.

Comment: Javascript doesn't reload templates in strings. You should write something like `%taskValue%`, then replace it using `this.results.innerHTML += this.taskBody.replace('%taskValue%', this.taskValue)` in addTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first instantiate the `Task`, the value of the `this.taskBody` is set as below:

```
<div class="task">
    <span>undefined</span>
    <span class="actions">
       
        <a class="edit-button" title="Edit Task">Edit</a>
        <button class="complete-button" title="Complete Task"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
        
    </span>
</div>
```

with `undefined` value, because at the moment of instantiation, the `taskValue` is undefined.

If your todo list items are added dynamically (which is the case), consider having a function which will enable dynamic replacement, like:

```
getTaskBody = item => `<div class="task">
    <span>${item}</span>
    <span class="actions">
       
        <a class="edit-button" title="Edit Task">Edit</a>
        <button class="complete-button" title="Complete Task"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
        
    </span>
</div>`;
```

and use it later in line 123, instead of:

```
this.results.innerHTML += this.taskBody;
```

do:

```
this.results.innerHTML += getTaskBody(this.taskValue);
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you! I figured that was the case, but was trying to save the HTML in a variable instead of a function. Thanks again